# How do I upload large files to Telegram in Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, aiogram

There are ≈ 2.5k archives of different size from 20kb to 2gb. They need to upload to telegram channel (not with links to other storages, clouds, etc.) Thought that it could be done through a bot (then I did not know about the 50mb limit).

Wrote the following code:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['send_files'])
async def send_files_handler(message: types.Message):
    files = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
    for files in files:
        with open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, file), 'rb') as f:
            try:
                # await bot.send_document(chat_id=CHAT_ID, document=f)
                await bot.send_document('CHENAL_ID', document=f)`
```

I write the command `/send_files` in the bot's PM, the bot starts sending all the files from the specified directory.
I tried to run it, I saw after loading a few files errors. I wrote a sending block in `try:` and added a function to write in txt paths to files that failed to send

```
try:
                await bot.send_document('CHENAL_ID', document=f)
            except:
                r_f = open(r'D:\test\erorr.txt','a')
                r_f.write(str(f)+'\n')
                f.close()`
```

Wrote a script to move the files from `erorr.txt` to a separate folder to see what's wrong with them later.
I realized that for some reason there were files up to 50mb and they are not in the channel. Repeated the algorithm again, but in a new directory and with a new file `erorr.txt`. Again, some of the files were downloaded and some were not. And I did it again many, many times.

I've seen [article on habr](https://habr.com/ru/articles/348234/) where they use "User-bot", he sends files to the bot, and it in turn sends the file to the desired chat.

In general, I need a working method for auto uploading files to tg channel up to 2gb.

Answer (score 2):

**Tip**, instead of moving those files etc, you could have checked the return value of [`bot.send_document`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), Telegram will let you know what you've done wrong.

---

The linked article seems to be using [telethon](/questions/tagged/telethon)<sup>[[github](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)]</sup>, a [python](/questions/tagged/python) library to create your *own Telegram Client* using [Telegram's MTProto Protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto).

Using Telethon's [send_file()](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file) method, you could send files from your own Telegram account, so you will not be limited to the [Bot limit of **50mb**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) but [(currently) **1.5GB**](https://telegram.org/blog/shared-files).

You could even use the [upload_file()](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.upload_file) method to just upload them to Telegram'
s server, without sending the message. Save the returned id's somewhere and to instantly send the file to somebody.

---

Examples can also be found in the [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file):

```py
# Normal files like photos
await client.send_file(chat, '/my/photos/me.jpg', caption="It's me!")

# Only documents
await client.send_file(chat, '/my/photos/photo.png', force_document=True)

# Photos as photo and document
file = await client.upload_file('photo.jpg')
await client.send_file(chat, file)                       # sends as photo
await client.send_file(chat, file, force_document=True)  # sends as document
```

Comment: How do I avoid having my account banned?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you could add some delay with uploading files to prevent Telegram thinking you're spamming